# Laravel 5.6 Many To Many Polymorphic Relations Table Structure

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to built many to many polymorphic relations Table structure. Choosen categorizables table is pivot. I am creating a table like the one below but I can not be sure of the correctness.

```
blogs
    id - integer
    name - string
    ...
videos
    id
    video_url

categories
    category_id - integer
    name - string

categorizables
    category_id - integer - unsigned
    categorizable_id - integer -unsigned
    categorizable_type - string - nullable (value likes 'App\Blog' )
```

Following code belongs to the categorizables table.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categorizables', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('categorizable_id');
            $table->string('categorizable_type');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->index(['category_id', 'categorizable_id']);
            $table->index(['categorizable_id', 'category_id']);
            $table->index('categorizable_type');
        });
    }
```

categories migration file is below

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->increments('tag_id');
           $table->string('name');
           $table->string('normalized');
           $table->timestamps();
           $table->index('normalized');
        });
```

How can I built structure or Am I going to true way?

Best Regards

Comment: I'm not very clear about some of the details of your table structures but generally you're approaching that in the right way (depends on what you're trying to achieve thought, but it makes sense ot me). Only thing left is to set up the relationships in the models the correct way. But there's a sufficient documentation on that.